# Adding count data at ticks in a ridgeplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sum, paste

Can I in an easy way, without changing the name of the individual observations, add/change the text manually of the ticks at the y-axis in a ggplot ridgeplot (see code below and example of figure). In addition to the text at each tick, I would like to add the number of datapoints for each tick (e.g. Species (n=XXX)), ideally using a sum and paste function.

Thank you in advance,

https://postimg.cc/nMQJBFDH

```
ggplot(ridge, aes(x = alder, y = species_group, fill = species_group)) +
  geom_density_ridges() +
  theme_ridges() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=10,color="black"), axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic", size=8)) +
  xlab("Age distribution, years") + ylab("") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) +  
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,100)) +
  xlim(0,100)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest approach would be to another column to your dataset which could then be mapped on the `y` aesthetic. However, if that is too cumbersome you could of course create a vector of counts which could then be glued to the axis labels via the `labels` argument of `scale_y_discrete`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `iris`:

```r
library(ggridges)
library(ggplot2)

counts_vec <- iris |> 
  dplyr::count(Species) |> 
  tibble::deframe()

counts_vec
#>     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#>         50         50         50

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density_ridges() +
  theme_ridges() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10, color = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic", size = 8)
  ) +
  labs(x = "Age distribution, years", y = NULL) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev, labels = ~ paste0(.x, " (n=", counts_vec[.x], ")"))
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181
```

[image]

And just a reference here the approach with adding a new column:

```r
iris <- iris |> 
  dplyr::add_count(Species) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(species_count = paste0(Species, " (n=", n, ")"))

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = species_count, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density_ridges() +
  theme_ridges() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10, color = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic", size = 8)
  ) +
  labs(x = "Age distribution, years", y = NULL) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181
```

[image]